# How to make the hover work for whole line including a floated icon

Tags: html, css

I want to make a hover for the whole line, but in my code below the hover is only working for the text. I want to make it for the whole line including `caret` and menu title.

I tried this code:

```js
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
    var $tog = $(this).next('.tog');
    $tog.slideToggle();
    if ($tog.hasClass('open')){
        $tog.removeClass('open');
        $(this).removeClass('caret-down');
    }else{
        $tog.addClass('open');
         $(this).addClass('caret-down');
    }

});
```

```css
ul, #myUL {
    list-style-type: none;
}
  
#myUL {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
  
.caret {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari 3.1+ */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox 2+ */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE 10+ */
    user-select: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
  
.caret::before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f078";
    color: #007BFF;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float:right;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
    transition: transform 0.6s;
  }
  
.caret-down::before {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(-180deg);  
}
  
.nested {
    display: none;
    margin: 10px;
}
  
.active {
    display: block;
}

.treeparent {
    /* display: table-cell; */
    overflow: auto;
    max-width: 350px;
    max-height: 350px;
    margin: auto;
    height: 35px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #007BFF;
    margin: 3px;
    width: 260px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 2px;
}

.treeparent:hover {
    background-color: #cee0f5;
    color: black;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}

.flip {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.ripple {
    background-position: center;
  }

.ripple:hover {
    background: #cee0f5 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 5%, #a8cdf7 1%) center/15000%;
}

.ripple:active {
    background-color: #6eb9f7;
    background-size: 100%;
    transition: background 0s;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #007bff;
    background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
    font-weight: bold;  
}


.nav-item { 
    margin-bottom: -8px; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 1<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
         <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
           <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
             <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
           </li>
           <li class="nav-item" rel="1">
             <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 2</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 2<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
         <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
           <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
             <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
           </li>
         </ul>
     </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

You can reproduce the problem --> https://jsfiddle.net/gL4ombkt/

How should I change my code to fix the problem?

Comment: FYI I've added the relevant code from the fiddle into the snippet so we can see the submenus. For future reference, all of the code that applies to the problem should in included directly in the question itself (you had included your HTML but the CSS was also important!). External links can break or change over time and the question would not be useful for other users if that happened :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block;` to `.caret{...}` class.

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: block;
}

.caret::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f078";
  color: #007BFF;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.nested {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.treeparent {
  /* display: table-cell; */
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #007BFF;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 260px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px;
}

.treeparent:hover {
  background-color: #cee0f5;
  color: black;
  transition: background 0.5s;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.ripple {
  background-position: center;
}

.ripple:hover {
  background: #cee0f5 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 5%, #a8cdf7 1%) center/15000%;
}

.ripple:active {
  background-color: #6eb9f7;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 1<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
        <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" rel="1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 2<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
        <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the CSS for the `hover` to apply to a block element that includes the text and `caret` (at the moment they are in an inline element and the caret is floating out of the parent).

You can achieve this by making `span.treeparent` a block element, e.g. `block` or `inline-block`

```
.menu-text li span{
  display: block;
}
```

If you also want the hover effect to apply to the items in the dropdown, you can apply the same styling as the `.treeparent:hover` like this:

```
.treeparent:hover, 
.nested.nav li:hover {
    background-color: #cee0f5;
    color: black;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}
```

**Working Example:** (Note that making the span a block element now also applies the CSS styling you were using with padding, width etc. that doen't work on an inline element)

```js
$(".treeparent").click(function () {
    var $tog = $(this).next('.tog');
    $tog.slideToggle();
    if ($tog.hasClass('open')){
        $tog.removeClass('open');
        $(this).removeClass('caret-down');
    }else{
        $tog.addClass('open');
         $(this).addClass('caret-down');
    }

});
```

```css
ul,
#myUL {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#myUL {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ddd;
}

.caret {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* Safari 3.1+ */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* Firefox 2+ */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.caret::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f078";
  color: #007BFF;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: right;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.6s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.6s;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
}

.caret-down::before {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
  /* Safari */
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.nested {
  display: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.treeparent {
  /* display: table-cell; */
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 350px;
  max-height: 350px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #007BFF;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 260px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #CFB;
  }

.menu-text li span{
  display: block;
}

.treeparent:hover, 
.nested.nav li:hover {
    background-color: #cee0f5;
    color: black;
    transition: background 0.5s;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.ripple {
  background-position: center;
}

.ripple:hover {
  background: #cee0f5 radial-gradient(circle, transparent 5%, #a8cdf7 1%) center/15000%;
}

.ripple:active {
  background-color: #6eb9f7;
  background-size: 100%;
  transition: background 0s;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active,
.nav-pills .show>.nav-link {
  color: #007bff;
  background-color: #f8f9fa!important;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-item {
  margin-bottom: -8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="myUL">
  <div class="menu-text">
    <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 1<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
        <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" rel="1">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <span class="caret treeparent ripple">Menu 2<i class="fas fa-chevron-down arrow"></i></span>
      <ul class="nested nav nav-pills flex-column tog">
        <li class="nav-item" rel="0">
          <a class="nav-link" href="javascript:window.location.reload(true)">Sub 1</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is a problem with your answer. When I click the hover it not works. It must click on the menu title. My expected outcome is when clicking the whole line output must show.

Comment: @user_v12 OK, I'll change it to work with that... I hadn't included the JS as I didn't know it was important :)

Comment: My tried code is working well on a normal laptop screen. But when I use a secondary monitor(widescreen high resolution) `menu titles (Menu 1, Menu 2)` has space with the sidebar. My real problem is that one. Yore's above answer does not fix my problem.

Comment: @user_v12 Do you mean the large space to the right of your menu? Can you explain what space you mean? The code you gave us doesn't mention a sidebar so we can't help you fix a problem if I don't know what it is! If you run the example, I've added backgrounds to make it clearer. I suspect the problem might be because `treeparent` cannot grow larger than 350px because the CSS has `max-width: 350px;`

Answer (score 0):

you please add padding to the right 100% to treeparent  class

```
.treeparent {
   .............
    padding-right: 100%;

}
```